# Group by does not provide accurate grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Attempting to create outputs that match the following screenshot:

[image]

When I attempt the following query:

```
SELECT t.amount, d.DOMAIN_NAME,td.month_number
FROM transaction t 
JOIN transaction_date td ON t.trans_date_key = td.trans_date_key
JOIN domain d ON t.domain_key = d.domain_key
WHERE td.month_number =7
ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

I get the output of:

[image]

When I implement this query:

```
SELECT t.amount, d.DOMAIN_NAME,td.month_number
FROM transaction t 
JOIN transaction_date td ON t.trans_date_key = td.trans_date_key
JOIN domain d ON t.domain_key = d.domain_key
WHERE td.month_number =7
GROUP BY domain_name
ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

I get the output of:

[image]

Why is my grouping only performing accurately on a few of the domain names, but not others?

Comment: try: **select  SUM(t.amount) , ....**

Comment: I have tried that option. Does not produce the target output. It sums the whole month of transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using `GROUP BY` correctly. You would need to use an aggregate function to sum the amounts. On the other hand, all non-aggregated columns should be listed in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Consider:

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) total_amount, d.domain_name, td.month_number
FROM transaction t 
INNER JOIN transaction_date td ON t.trans_date_key = td.trans_date_key
INNER JOIN domain d ON t.domain_key = d.domain_key
WHERE td.month_number = 7
GROUP BY d.domain_name, td.month_number
ORDER BY total_amount DESC;
```

What happens with the way you used `GROUP BY` is that MySQL actually picks a random record out of those that have the same `domain_name`. On most other RDBMS (and in non-ancient versions of MySQL), this would have generated a syntax error.